# Is there any method called specifically when an iPhone app is opened via the View button in an interactive Push Notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

My iPhone app has background push enabled.  When the push notification is received, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` is immediately called in the AppDelegate.  The push notification is interactive, so it has the "Options" button.  When the Options button is tapped, it shows the View button, 2 actions, and the Close button.  When either of the 2 action buttons are tapped, `application:handleActionWithIdentifier` is called in the App Delegate, which is what I want.  However, when the View button is tapped the app opens, but `application:handleActionWithIdentifier` is not called.  Is there any method called specifically when the app is opened via the View Button?